# PHP variable life cycle

Tags: php, variables, session

Ok I'm trying to pass a variable, but I have a problem.
All happens in one PHP file, and simplified code is like this:

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <html>
                ...some HTML code...
    <?php
          $var = 100      // variable that i need
          $_SESSION['passover'] = $var; 

     ?>                

     ...HTML code with 'submit' form 
      </html>

     <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){..do something...}
      $var_again = $_SESSION['passover']   //problem!
      print_r($_SESSION);  

      session_destroy();  
      ?>
```

Before I press submit I get output like:    Array ( [passover] => dog.jpg )
After I press submit I get:                 Array ( )

What am I doing wrong?
In this case variable is a file name, but I;ve tried with simple numbers and it won't work either.

Comment: remove session_destroy from code

Comment: Interesting, it helped :) Could you please explain? Session_destroy was at the very end of code.

Comment: @Cornelius Whenever you call `session_destroy` you remove the session from PHP's session management. It's supposed to be used on 'logout' actions and such.

Comment: Yes but it's interesting for me as a beginner in PHP to see that it destroyed the session variable even before it was printed out. That's one line before the session_destroy command was called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove session_destroy from code, follow this logic:

1. You start session (ok)
2. you put variable into session (ok)
3. you print variable from session (ok)
4. you deleted all information from session (not ok)
5. on next request (after submit) you have empty session, because of p4

Comment: No , no that's not the line. It gos like this:

1. start session
2. put variable into session
3. submit form
4. print session variable
5. destroy session

Comment: @Cornelius nope, you're always destroy session

Comment: Interesting. So the position of destroy_session in the code doesn't matter much? So when does this session end, and how long do this session variables last?

Comment: @Cornelius position matters, but in your code session_destroy was called for each request

Comment: Yes, but LoL... before that "each request" to destroy session was a print line. Why did it print an empty array, even the first time, before it got to the destroy_session line...

Comment: @Cornelius I don't understand you, looks like problem not with session but with overall understanding how server side program is executed, what passed to/from browser and how session works

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I wasn't looking for sessions specifically anyway, but for a way to store my variable somehow that it doesn't go away. After much reading I've found out that the good way to do it is by using sessions. Still haven't got to sessions in details.

Answer (score 0):

Session_destroy() is definitely the culprit.
Also, I imagine you left a couple semicolons out of your sample code by accident, but the semicolon is missing **twice**..

```
$var = 100  **;**    // variable that i need
.
.
$var_again = $_SESSION['passover'] **;**  //problem!
```

Plus, you actually used two variable names there: $var and $var_again.  If that's both meant to be the same thing, this could be a problem, too.

Comment: YEs, missing semicolon was mistaken here, because I was having a bad time writing this code. I'm always pressing tab, which doesn't work here.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if removing session_destroy() doesn't fix this for you.  You should be fine removing it.  Comment it out first to test.  Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: Yes, it did help. That was my first answer.